# Talend repository access denied for marketo-soap-sdk 2.7

Tags: talend

The artifact we used now challenged for user/password.

https://artifacts-oss.talend.com/nexus/content/repositories/TalendOpenSourceRelease/org/talend/libraries/marketo-soap-sdk/2.7

how to resolve the maven issue?

Is there any policy enforced for authenticating the repository if so how to get new user/password for talend artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Talend has password protected some of the Nexus repositories needed to build Talend from the sourcecode:
https://artifacts-oss.talend.com/nexus/content/repositories/TalendOpenSourceRelease/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).